# How does R convert characters to numbers?

Tags: r, type-conversion, character, numeric, letter

Not a particularly useful question but...

I accidentally converted a character column (with a combination letters and numbers) to a numeric column; it got me wondering how exactly does R make this conversion?

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how the original character vector was encoded. If it is a true character vector, any value that is not a number gets replaced with NA:

```
dat <- c("a","b","c","d","a1","2b", "3")
as.numeric(dat)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA  3
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

However, if the vector was a *factor*, then R uses the factor levels to assign the numeric values:

```
dat <- as.factor(c("a","b","c","d","a1","2b", "3"))
dat
# [1] a  b  c  d  a1 2b 3 
# Levels: 2b 3 a a1 b c d
as.numeric(dat)
# [1] 3 5 6 7 4 1 2
```